# Not going in for loop

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jtable, system.out

I have the following code

```
ArrayList<Integer> Analysis = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> designInitialBuild = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> Production = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> Strategy = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> Testing = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println("jTableLength: " + jTable1.getRowCount());
for(int xn=0;xn==jTable1.getRowCount();xn++){
   System.out.println(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(xn, 3).toString());
   switch(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(xn, 3).toString()){      
      case "Analysis":
          Analysis.add(xn);
          break;
      case "Design & Initial Build":
          designInitialBuild.add(xn);
          break;
      case "Production":
          Production.add(xn);
          System.out.println("Production");
          break;
      case "Strategy":
          Strategy.add(xn);
          break;
      case "Testing":
          Testing.add(xn);
          break;
      default:
          System.out.println("I am Broken");
          break;
    } 
}
System.out.println(Production.size());
```

When I debug the code it shows that the variable xn has a value of -8, it never goes into the for loop and does the first "println"
Before the loop where I did `System.out.println("jTableLength: " + jTable1.getRowCount());` it displays 48..... i'm so very confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition on your `for` loop is wrong.  The `for` loop will only execute while the condition is `true`.  Try less than:

```
for(int xn=0;xn < jTable1.getRowCount();xn++){
```

This way, the loop will keep executing if `xn` is less than the row count, and it will stop then `xn` reaches the row count.

Comment: Ok I feel like a complete idiot, for some odd reason I thought the for loop was going to run until the condition is true... thanx for the quick response

Comment: Be sure to accept rgettman's answer to close this question @user2698080